# Backup a Time Machine .sparsebundle to Amazon Glacier

Tags: backup, time-machine

I want to make an off-site backup of my Time Machine, and Amazon Glacier seems to be a cheap and reliable place to put large files in.

Anyone has experience using Glacier in such settings? Any tips on how to upload the files there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "s3cmd" tool seems to be quite popular for copying files to Amazon Glacier, either manually or via scripts:

https://s3tools.org/s3cmd

You could also use commercial tools such as CloudBerry Backup to automatize synchronizing the Time Machine sparsebundle with Amazon Glacier.